# Clicking on a button with attribute role within div tag using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, button

How to click on the `button` with the below HTML tag

```
<div class="_1WZqU PNlAR" role="button">OK</div>
```

I tried with the followings:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("_1WZqU PNlAR")).click();
```

I got the following error message:

> invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: Add HTML source, format your code, add more information what `doesn't work` mean. Do you get an exception or element is just not clicked?

Comment: Did you try to click using javascript?

Comment: The actual error you are getting is because you have put two class names in `By.className()`. You must chose one of the classes or convert it to a CSS selector, `By.cssSelector("._1WZqU.PNlAR")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using , button tag is not there in the HTML

```
//div[text()='OK']
```

use this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='OK']")).click();
```

you can also use `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement OKBtnElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='OK']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", OKBtnElement );
```

Comment: Good catch on the `div` tag!

Comment: I don't think one should use JavascriptExecutor it doesn't work like a humans click...
Yet in some cases it is inevitable... OP should try  `WebDriverWait` first...

Comment: IMO @MosheSlavin is pretty correct to mention that, to mock the human alike behavior the strong, powerful and proven `click()` should be tried out first and _javascript_ based `click()` should be the last resort. Else these answers won't be useful to future readers and would be prone to downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='OK']")));
element.click();
```

HOpe this helps you!

Comment: _WebDriverWait_ is inevitable as the element is clearly a dynamically generated element.